# Parsing specific strings from binary files

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, binary, bitstring

I need to process all binary files(PE32) from a folder.
I'm looking to extract a specific string from each of these executables.
The strings are sometimes found in little-endian, in some files they are big-endian.
The string I'm looking for in every binary file is an address: example.site.com/home.asp
The home.asp is always present (either in little or big-endian)

Looking to do this with bitstring.
I'm thinking I need to use s.find(), and seek to home.asp into the file and then extract the previous X bytes, but the address length is always changing.

Maybe I need to list all strings (little and big E) from the binary first and grep that output for home.asp?

Via bash:
'''strings -e l'''
'''strings -e b''' 
gets strings from the binaries, then I can grep for home.asp, but I need to do this in python, and being able to do on all files recursively.

Get all addresses from all files.

Comment: can you please share some example input and expected output with your approaching codes so that we can help?

Comment: use 4 spaces at the front of each line that you want displayed as code, or use the `{}` tool in the Edit menu on selected text. Good luck.